# R - Bind vectors from loop into one data.frame

Tags: r

I am working with a large dataset. My goal is to get the sum for certain events (as coded in the dataset) for particular countries over time. The dataset is so large that I have to load it by month with a function.
The data is from the GDELT dataset, which is available here: http://gdelt.utdallas.edu/data/backfiles/?O=D I have converted the csv's to Rdata for quicker reading and writing. It is a dataset with 57 different variables.

```
# Create empty dataframes for all countries to later store data in.
Countries <- c("MAR","DZA","TUN","LBY","EGY","ISR",
               "JOR","SYR","TUR","GEO","UKR","RUS","BLR")
loadNames <- function(CountryName) {
  a <- data.frame()
  assign(CountryName, a, pos = .GlobalEnv)
}
lapply(Countries,loadNames)

loadMonth <- function(MonthName) {
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, initial = 0, char = "=", style = 1, width = 10)

  # Load the month.
  load(paste("/Users/mennoschellekens/Dropbox/HCSS-workinprogress/GDELT/Rdata/",MonthName,".RData", sep = ""), envir=environment())
  colnames(Month) <- names(Header.57)

  # Create a subset of relevant data for faster looping.
  y <- subset(Month, ((Actor1CountryCode == "SYR" | Actor1CountryCode =="MAR" | Actor1CountryCode =="DZA" | Actor1CountryCode == "TUN" | Actor1CountryCode == "LBY" | Actor1CountryCode == "EGY" | Actor1CountryCode == "ISR" | Actor1CountryCode == "JOR" | Actor1CountryCode == "TUR" | Actor1CountryCode == "GEO" | Actor1CountryCode == "UKR" | Actor1CountryCode == "RUS" | Actor1CountryCode == "BLR") & (Actor2CountryCode == "SYR" | Actor2CountryCode == "MAR" | Actor2CountryCode == "DZA" | Actor2CountryCode == "TUN" | Actor2CountryCode == "LBY" | Actor2CountryCode == "EGY" | Actor2CountryCode == "ISR" | Actor2CountryCode == "JOR" | Actor2CountryCode == "TUR" | Actor2CountryCode == "GEO" | Actor2CountryCode == "UKR" | Actor2CountryCode == "RUS" | Actor2CountryCode == "BLR")))

  #Define the events I want. 
  QuadCat <- c(1,2,3,4)

  # Define the countries I want.
  CountryString <- c("MAR","DZA", "TUN","LBY","EGY","ISR",
                     "JOR","SYR","TUR","GEO","UKR","RUS","BLR")
  CountryData <- c(MAR,DZA,TUN,LBY,EGY,ISR,JOR,SYR,TUR,GEO,UKR,RUS,BLR)

  # I want to check the above events for each country, using the function 'Check Events' with an embedded 'for loop'.
  CheckEvents <- function(CountryData,CountryString) {
    x <- subset(y, ((Actor1CountryCode == CountryString) & (Actor2CountryCode == CountryString)))

    # This is the problem:
    for (Y in QuadCat) {
      e[[Y]] <- (sum(x$QuadClass == Y))
      e <- rbind(CountryData,c(e))
      assign(CountryString, as.data.frame(e), pos = .GlobalEnv)
    }
  }
  mapply(CheckEvents, CountryData = CountryData, CountryString = CountryString)    
} ###### END
```

The output of the first run gives a vector with the four numbers, which is good, and then stored in the Global Environment. However, when I try to bind that result to a new result with `rbind()`, `cbind()` or `merge()`, it gives me very strange results. Most notably, it refuses to read `CountryData` as a vector, but only takes the last value in the vector. I don't understand what it is doing and why it won't bind.

Comment: The object `Month` of which you attempt to take a subset is not defined.

Comment: The `loadNames` function also seems unnecessary, or at least inefficient.

Comment: Because it is formatted in Rdata, loading it already creates the object 'Month' in my workspace. Therefore, this code works for me without defining the object.

Comment: Could you post some data, or at least some similar data? Also, where is `e` defined?

Comment: The dataset has 57 variables, so I won't post it here. Given it is publicly available, it put in a link to the data above. I have not defined 'e', but ' e[[Y]] <- (sum(x$QuadClass == Y))' produces a nice vector, so I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) on how to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below will get you what you want, as a list. You can then reshape it however you want. Your example code, however, is incredibly confusing and involves some potentially dangerous elements like using `assign` and `subset` inside functions. You also seemed to have a lot of superfluous code. I imagine all of these things are what was causing you problems.

```
Countries <- c("MAR","DZA","TUN","LBY","EGY","ISR",
               "JOR","SYR","TUR","GEO","UKR","RUS","BLR")

loadMonth <- function(MonthName) {
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, initial = 0, char = "=", style = 1, width = 10)

  # Load the month
  load(paste("/Users/mennoschellekens/Dropbox/HCSS-workinprogress/GDELT/Rdata/",MonthName,".RData", sep = ""), envir=environment())
  colnames(Month) <- names(Header.57)

  y <- Month[(Month$Actor1CountryCode %in% Countries) &
             (Month$Actor2CountryCode %in% Countries),] # subset
  CheckEvents <- function(CountryString) {
    x <- y[(y$Actor1CountryCode == CountryString) &
           (y$Actor2CountryCode == CountryString),]
    # 1:4 below was your values of QuadCat
    sapply(1:4, function(Y) sum(x$QuadClass == Y)) # should return a vector
  }
  # build list of vectors from `CheckEvents`, one for each country
  out <- lapply(Countries, CheckEvents)
  names(out) <- Countries
  return(out)
}
loadMonth("January") # get the list for one month; not sure how you have months named
```

Comment: That is very helpful, thank you! I do have a follow up question. How can I save the vectors per country, each vector (corresponding with each month) becoming a row? I would like to end up with object 'SYR' with 162 rows (for my 162 months).

Comment: Try something like `do.call(rbind, object)` where `object` is the output of your `loadMonth()` function.